# Unable to install Jenkins Slave - as a service

Tags: jenkins, devops, master-slave

I am getting below error when I try to install Jenkins Slave as a service.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance. I am an admin user on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it happens is because the Jenkins slave tries to make connection with the Master and gets a denial.

What you have to do is basically to enable make sure all these services are running (Both in Master and Slave):

1. Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
2. Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
3. Remote Registry
4. Secondary Login
5. Windows Management Instrumentation
6. Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)

Comment: Slave is already connected to master. Check 1st image. Problem occurs when I try to install it as a service.

Comment: Can you repeat the process and copy the logs from your jenkinsfolder\remoting\logs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for the replies.

The issue was with the file permissioning. I use cygwin, and changed the file permissions to 777 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably executing the script without administrative rights, right? Add the rights and execute